# Raspberry Pi stuck with blinking cursor after reboot

Tags: boot-issues, raspberry-pi-os

I have an issue when using the [Raspberry Pi 7" Touch Screen Display](https://a.co/d/1rxamLc) connected via the ribbon cable (DSI Interface).
The issue is that after most reboots, all I get is a blinking cursor in the upper-left corner of the screen.

This issue is intermittent.

What logs should I look at to diagnose this issue.

I do not have a space issue on my SD Card, it's only 10% full

I am on a Pi3B+

```
$ uname -a
Linux sandysclock 6.1.21-v7+ #1639 SMP Fri Mar 24 16:56:29 GMT 2023 armv7l GNU/Linux

$ cat /etc/os-release 
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

[image: Cursor is blinking at irregular intervals]

Comment: NOTE id you are running 6.1.21-v7+ you have performed something else - probably `rpi-update` "You should not use rpi-update on any system unless recommended to do so by a Raspberry Pi engineer"

Answer (score 0):

For my case, if I power-cycled the Pi, it worked, if I `sudo reboot`, I would experience the issue.

After some digging on the raspberry pi forums, I found what I think may be the answer:

edit the `/boot/config.txt` file and comment/remove:

```
display_auto_detect=1
```

and add/ensure these two line are present:

```
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-v3d
dtoverlay=vc4-kms-dsi-7inch
```